# How to keep music in iCloud but not downloaded?

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, icloud, music

I bought an album via iTunes on my Mac. On my iPhone, the album is not stored locally (I need a wireless connection in order to play it). However the album got downloaded onto my iPad automatically.

How can I remove the album from iPad? And of course not delete it from my library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your iPad, go to **Settings** → **General** → **Storage & iCloud Usage** → **Manage Storage** → **Music**.

[image: Manage Music Storage]

From there, you can either **Edit** or directly *swipe left* on any artist to delete all their songs. If you just want to delete individual albums or songs, you can drill down by tapping an artist or album, respectively, then *swipe left* to delete each item one by one.

If you want to go thermonuclear, you can simply *swipe left* on **All Songs**. Do note that this operation takes some time to complete, up to several minutes. So just let iOS do its work, and soon enough you should have your storage back.

Once you’re done, in order to keep songs from being downloaded in the future, go back to **Settings** → **iTunes & App Store**, then toggle **Music** *Off* under **AUTOMATIC DOWNLOADS**.

[image: Automatic Downloads]

Answer (score -1):

Keep the internet connection off and remove it. The album will be removed from your iPad and kept in the cloud.